# Scala case classes and Hash Collision

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am facing Hash Collision issue when i generated the equals and hashCode methods from Eclipse IDE.

I am planning to use `Scala API` `case classes` for the same purpose, since its creating `equals` and `hashcode` automatically.

Is Scala generated methods are good enough to handle the Hash Collision issue?

Anyone faced the Hash Collision issues while using Case Classes?

Comment: you mean different objects are represented by the same hashcode?

Comment: What do you mean with "from Eclipse IDE"? What language is Eclipse generating? What classes are colliding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to be clear: hash collisions are *unavoidable* if your data has more bits than your hash code, simply because there are more possible values than possible hash codes.

However, the scala case class hash code is using the [MurmurHash3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$) hash algorithm, which gives a pretty good distribution of hash values for a non-cryptographic hash function. So hash collisions of case classes should be relatively rare. You still need to handle them properly in your code though!

Another remark: your code *must* handle hash code collisions properly. But they are rare with a good hash function. So if you really want to be thorough, you should have tests where you intentionally have multiple case classes with the same hash code.

Answer (score 2):

Beware, Scala case classes are by definition objects which only depend on their parameter values, meaning that you will get the same hashes and equals if you construct two instances with the same parameters.

```
scala> case class Example(number: Int, label: String)
defined class Example

scala> val e1 = Example(42, "test")
e1: Example = Example(42,test)

scala> val e2 = Example(42, "test")
e2: Example = Example(42,test)

scala> e1 == e2
res0: Boolean = true

scala> e1.hashCode
res1: Int = 1424814261

scala> e2.hashCode
res2: Int = 1424814261

scala> class OtherExample(val number: Int, val label: String)
defined class OtherExample

scala> val o1 = new OtherExample(42, "test")
o1: OtherExample = OtherExample@6f077e50

scala> val o2 = new OtherExample(42, "test")
o2: OtherExample = OtherExample@1b0c366b

scala> o1 == o2
res3: Boolean = false

scala> o1.hashCode
res4: Int = 1862762064

scala> o2.hashCode
res5: Int = 453785195
```

So, you have to ask yourself about the exact distribution of parameters you intend to have. If you want to distinguish between instances with the same parameters, maybe regular classes are a better option — you'll still get an auto-generated equals and hashCode.